# Rename an environment with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have an environment called `doors` and I would like to rename it to `django` for the [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/).

I've noticed that if I just rename the folder `~/.virtualenvs/doors` to `django`, I can now call `workon django`, but the environment still says `(doors)hobbes3@hobbes3`.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can use:

```
cpvirtualenv oldenv newenv
rmvirtualenv oldenv
```

So in your case:

```
cpvirtualenv doors django
rmvirtualenv doors
```

Comment: Just a heads up, there is currently a warning that `cpvirtualenv` may not work properly due to some hard-coded path information. Here's the docs: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#cpvirtualenv

Comment: I just tried this and it created the "copy" with python2.7, even though the oldenv I was trying to copy used python3.7..... sad.

Comment: I just got Python 3.7.3 after running cpvirtualenv, as expetcted.

Answer (score 8):

if you do:

```
$ ack-grep -ai doors ~/.virtualenvs/django/bin
```

you'll notice that will have `doors` as location and not django, you'll to change each file with the new location.

solution:
 after renamed the folder execute the command below.

```
$ sed -i "s/doors/django/g" ~/.virtualenvs/django/bin/*
```

now if you do:

```
$ workon django
(django)hobbes3@hobbes3
```